# XHR Multipart File Upload Spring Boot Issue

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

I have an upload progress bar that works upon file input and when the bar reaches 100%, there is no error. But as I print the contents of the file in Spring Boot, I notice that the code within the for loop does not run. Here is the code. Please help and thank you!

JavaScript:

```
function upload(file) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("newFile", file);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/upload');
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        console.log("xhr onload function");
    };
    var progressBar = document.querySelector('progress');
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            progressBar.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
            progressBar.textContext = progressBar.value;
        }
    };
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Spring Boot:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String upload(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) {

    // This prints [Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;@........].
    System.out.println(files);
    for (MultipartFile file : files) {
        // This doesn't get printed.
        System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
    }
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript you are adding file to ‘newFile’ variable but on spring side you are extracting file from request param ‘files’.

Are you uploading multiple files? It doesn’t seems so. Try only with Multipart.

Comment: For now, at least 1 file will do. Works now. Thanks @Aman Garg

Answer (score 1):

Because `MultipartFile[]` files were just initialized but does not contain any  array of values.

Change the

`public String upload(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files)`

to

`public String upload(@RequestPart(value = "files", required = true) MultipartFile[] files)`

Comment: I tried that but the for-loop I mentioned above still doesn't run.

Comment: Then the issue is in framing your request.